# Informix 'UNLOAD TO' generates backslashes when I export table as CSV

Tags: csv, informix

Whenever I try to export a table from an Informix database to a CSV file, I find that the generated file contains backslashes. This is the query I used:

```
UNLOAD TO 'C:/Documents and Settings/XXXX/XXXX/test.txt' DELIMITER '|'
select * from xxx
```

This is an example of the results I get in the CSV file

```
A|B|C|D|E|F\
This\
Is\
SOME\
TEXT\
|
A2|B2|C3|D4|E5|F6
```

If anyone knows how to resolve this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad the proposed solution works for you, but the question arises "what should happen if the data contains necessary newlines" (so mapping newlines to blanks or whatever isn't an option)?  There are various standards — and that's a major part of the problem.

Comment: Yes that would be a real issue, but in my case I don't mind losing newlines since I was just attempting to use the generated CSV elsewhere ( in an excel sheet ) for visualization, so that's why I needed to remove blackslashes. But for reloading the file again to a table, I know I should use 'LOAD' command from dbAccess and it automatically handles the blackslashes and newlines.
Thanks anyway for you support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because are newline characters in the values of this column.
You can remove the newlines with `replace` function.

First you must enable newline in quoted strings running this stored procedure

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('T');
```

Then you can use `replace` to remove (or change to another character) newlines from the column that has newlines (in this example is **column3**)

```
UNLOAD TO 'C:/Documents and Settings/XXXX/XXXX/test.txt' DELIMITER '|'
SELECT column1, column2, replace(column3, "
", "") 
  FROM xxx
```

Note that in the call to function replace are only a newline between the two firsts quotes in the second parameter, the third parameter is the value for which you want to replace the newlines.